# I am getting an error with Tweepy and I am not sure why it says I am passing more positions

Tags: python, tweepy

When I run the following code, I get back an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(api.get_user(user))
TypeError: get_user() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

It seems the only thing being passed is the string in user.

```
import os
import tweepy

api_key = os.environ['api_key']
api_secret = os.environ['api_secret']
access_secret = os.environ['accesssecret']
access_token = os.environ['accesstoken']
bearer = os.environ['bearer']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.Client(bearer, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_secret, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

user = 'testuser'
print(api.get_user(user))
```

Comment: i think correct way to call api would be with `api = tweepy.API(auth)` you are using `tweepy.Client` instead. Then you could call `api.get_user(id="<id_here>")`

Comment: @BijayRegmi thank you, that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) changed [`API.get_user`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.1.0/api.html#tweepy.API.get_user) to not accept any positional arguments.
The 1 positional argument being referred to in the error is `self`.
You can pass `user` as the `screen_name` (or `user_id`) keyword argument instead.